# Make all rules in a CSS file apply only to descendants of id

Tags: css

I have a CSS with a bunch of rules. I have found that those rules are conflicting with other parts of my application. The solution is to make those rules valid only to descendants (direct or not) of a certain id:

```
<div id="thisOne">
    <!-- the CSS rules should be active ONLY here -->
</div>

#thisOne p { color: red; }
```

But it would be very ugly to precede all rules (dozens of them!) in the CSS file with the `#thisOne` selector. Is there a better way?

Comment: Use SCSS or the like to allow you to nest rules within `#thisOne { }`. Vanilla CSS does not support this.

Comment: Completely new to that. When you say "the like", what do you mean? What options do I have? Are you talking about less/sass? Are the options scss/less/sass then? Any other options? Any advice on which way to go? I think a big rabbit hole would open here ...

Comment: [A bunch](http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/how-to-choose-the-right-css-preprocessor), generally you're looking for something called a "CSS preprocessor".

Comment: Why can you not use `#thisone *{ }` if they share similar attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Less, a CSS pre-processor](http://lesscss.org/) to help with such things. I also use an a piece of software called [Crunch](http://crunchapp.net/). It can, however, be downloaded from [here](https://github.com/matthew-dean/Crunch).

To give you an idea how it works, let's take your example.

Under less (and before compiling)

```
#thisOne {
    p {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

You can then add to the rule as you need. ie:

```
#thisOne {
    width:300px;
    margin-left:50px;
    h1 {
        font-weight:lighter;
        color:blue;
    }
    p {
        color:red;
    }
}
```

You can do a lot more than this. Check it out. I've become a convert.

Answer (score 1):

You could always apply a custom class that had styling properties in it, so then it's not tied to the ID or component itself. So for instance, this might be an option for you (that is also re-usable throughout your app):

**CSS**

```
.text-gray { color: gray; }
.text-blue { color: blue; }
.nav { list-style: none; padding-left: 0; }
.nav > li > a { color: green; }
#thisOne .nav > li > a { color: red; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="thisOne">
  <div class="text-gray">Navigation</div>
  <ul class="nav">
    <li><a href="#">Link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
  </ul>
  <p class="text-blue">Come check out my new site here!</p>
</div>
```

If you want to precede your CSS with the ID selector, then using a CSS pre-processor would suit you well. A CSS pre-processor will help you cut down on the code you have to write. Below is a quick example of how to write code in a pre-processor, as well as how it will compile.

```
#thisOne {
  p { color: green; }
  ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    > li {
      float: left;
      > a { color: red; }
    } 
  } 
}
```

Above compiles to plain CSS...

```
#thisOne p { color: green; }
#thisOne ul { 
  list-style: none;
  padding-left: 0;
}
#thisOne ul > li { float: left; }
#thisOne ul > li > a { color: red; }
```

Depending on your development environment, different pre-processors might better suit the project. They are all quite similar, and I think it might be fun for you to read about them and maybe even start using one.

Answer (score 0):

You can add Class to all p elements inside "thisOne" div with jQuery:

```
$("#thisOne p").addClass("redItem");
```

and then change it from css:

```
.redItem { color: red; }
```

Comment: What does have to do with my question? I want that a *bunch* of CSS rules are only active for descendants of a certain element (selected by id). I would prefer not to prefix each of the CSS rules with the id selector. That is why I ask. With your (complicated) suggestion, I still need to modify every rule in my CSS file.

Answer (score 0):

It's not totally ideal, but if every element already has some identifier, you can actually stack multiple selectors (separated by commas) on a single rule set:

```
#thisOne *,
#thatOne *,
#anotherOne *,
#two *
{
    color: red;
}
```

Or, if you only want direct children of the elements:

```
#thisOne > *,
#thatOne > *,
#anotherOne > *,
#two > *
{
    color: red;
}
```

`*` is a catch all in CSS, it will match any element, so `#thisOne *` will select all children of elements with the ID "thisOne".

It's not so wonderfully automated, but it saves a lot of space (you can save further space by putting them all on one line) and means not having to update dozens of rules every time something changes.

Comment: Thanks, but I have **dozens** of rules. I do not want to prefix each rule with the id selector. Your suggestion does nothing to prevenet that

Comment: @gonvaled Ahhh, I misunderstood your question.  I thought you meant you didn't want to make dozens of selectors for the child elements.  Editing answer now with a possible fix.

Comment: @gonvaled updated.  It still might not be super helpful to your specific case, but I already had an answer in, so I might as well bring it as close as possible for anyone else who comes by to read this.